# How to delete orphaned mailboxes

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2011

I have no clue how this could happen:

`Get-MailboxStatistics -Server` returns 2 exactly equal entries `Office [Foo Software]` [It shows the used format]. One mailbox has 411 `ItemCount`, the other has 7.

In the Exchange Management Console there is no user associated to these mailboxes and `Get-Mailbox` does NOT return these 2 entries. `Get-User` shows users which have another mailboxes.
It looks to me as Exchange has here some inconsistency.

Also, in Exchange Console under Recipient configuration I see a disconnected mailbox with the name `Office [Foo Software]` - Trying to connect it fails because no proper user is found.

How can I delete this 2 equal and orphaned mailboxes? It's true, I had users with this name but I deleted them in the Exchange Management Console.

Environment:

- Exchange Server 2010
- SBS 2011 Standard

---

***Update:***

In the meantime I could at least delete the one mailbox with 411 `ItemCount`. Also, the above mentioned disconnected mailbox disappeared from the Exchange Management Console.

`Get-MailboxDatabase | Get-MailboxStatistics | Where{ $_.DisplayName -eq "Office [Foo Software]" } |fl DisplayName, Database, Identity, DisconnectReason` returns now this:

```
DisplayName      : Office [Foo Software]
Database         : Mailbox Database
Identity         : f3ed13de-ae8a-4c0a-9d4d-b641d35e0335
DisconnectReason :
```

When I try to disable this mailbox with `Disable-Mailbox -Identity "f3ed13de-ae8a-4c0a-9d4d-b641d35e0335"` then I get the error that the mailbox doesn't exist.

I have to disable it first because when I try to remove the mailbox I am asked for the `MailboxState` but it cannot be empty.

***So, now the question is, how can I delete the mailbox using its `uuid`?***

Answer (score 0):

With this steps I could delete the remaining `Office [Foo Software]` mailbox:

1. Run in the Exchange Powershell `Get-MailboxStatistics -Server '<ServerName>' | WHERE {$_.ObjectClass -eq "Mailbox"} | FL DisplayName,LastLoggedOnUserAccount,MailboxGuid`.
2. `LastLoggedOnUserAccount` has the name of the user which was previously assigned to this mailbox.
3. Create this user again **BUT ONLY** in the AD - **NOT as an Exchange user**.
4. Connect manually the new AD user with `Connect-Mailbox -Database "Mailbox Database" -Identity "Office [Foo Software]" -User <LastLoggedOnUserAccount>` to the mailbox.
5. Delete the user in the Exchange Management Console. Now its mailbox is marked as `Disabled`.
6. Remove the mailbox with `Remove-Mailbox -Database "Mailbox Database" -StoreMailboxIdentity "f3ed13de-ae8a-4c0a-9d4d-b641d35e0335"` where `StoreMailboxIdentity` is the value returned in 1) as `MailboxGuid`

---

I don't claim this is the simplest way, but it worked for me. Now both mailboxes with the same `DisplayName` have been successfully removed from the Exchange.